# why is awk sub changing my input when letters are present?

Tags: awk

I have an XML file with the structure below:

```
    <diskTypes>
        <diskType typeName="data001" sectors="5859356127" sectorSize="512"/>
        <diskType typeName="data002" sectors="23437457375" sectorSize="512"/>
        <diskType typeName="data003" sectors="46882764767" sectorSize="512"/>
    </diskTypes>
```

I want to use awk to add a comment at the end of the first line which includes a serial number. My desired output is this:

```
    <diskTypes>
        <diskType typeName="data001" sectors="5859356127" sectorSize="512"/> <!--serial=051161dc00000009-->
        <diskType typeName="data002" sectors="23437457375" sectorSize="512"/>
        <diskType typeName="data003" sectors="46882764767" sectorSize="512"/>
    </diskTypes>
```

to attempt to make this work I have come up with this awk command:

```
/usr/bin/awk '/<diskType typeName=".*\/>$/ && n == 0 { sub(/<diskType typeName=".*/, $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " <!--serial="051161dc00000009"-->"); ++n } { print }' Media1.cfgx > editedVol0.xml
```

however the result I end up with is this:

```
    <diskTypes>
        <diskType typeName="data001" sectors="5859356127" sectorSize="512"/> <!--serial=51161-->
        <diskType typeName="data002" sectors="23437457375" sectorSize="512"/>
        <diskType typeName="data003" sectors="46882764767" sectorSize="512"/>
    </diskTypes>
```

I dont understand what in awk is converting my input for the serial comment of **051161dc00000009** into the result in my file of **51161**

If my input does not contain any letters like this:

```
05116100000009 instead of 051161dc00000009
```

my result gets closer, looking like this:

```
...  <!--serial=5116100000009--> ...
```

but even then, for some reason awk is cutting off the first 0.

Can someone please help me fix this awk statement, and help me understand why I am losing the 0 when processing a serial that it made up of all numbers, and why I lose everything after the 51161 when any letters are involved?

Comment: put the number in the quotes as well.  To insert double quotes use `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I don't understand what your code is attempting, but just do this instead to convert the input you posted to the output you posted

```
$ awk '/<diskTypes>/{c=0} {print $0 (++c==2 ? " <!--serial=051161dc00000009-->" : "")}' file
<diskTypes>
    <diskType typeName="data001" sectors="5859356127" sectorSize="512"/> <!--serial=051161dc00000009-->
    <diskType typeName="data002" sectors="23437457375" sectorSize="512"/>
    <diskType typeName="data003" sectors="46882764767" sectorSize="512"/>
</diskTypes>
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of what this is doing? I'd like to understand it better.

Comment: But it's far simpler than the awk script you posted so - what part do you not understand? Is it the [ternary expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)?

Comment: The c=0 and ++c==2 section

Comment: c is a variable that's used as a count of lines. I set it to zero whenever I find <diskTypes> in the input, and increment it for every line. When it equals 2 (i.e. it's the line after <diskTypes>) then I add the extra text to $0. Add a print statement like `{print c, $0}` if it's not clear what its value is at each line.

Comment: I tried this and the result that came back was:
       <diskTypes>
        <diskType typeName="meta" sectors="2146547679" sectorSize="512"/> <!--serial=03c3ffbb00000001 --> <!--serial=051161dc00000009-->

Comment: Then either your input data doesn't look like the sample you posted or you copy/pasted my script wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of testing what I've found is that By adding "" after a space at the end of the number it tells awk to treat the previous block of text/numbers as a string. To make sure this works, I also needed to remove the quotes that were around the string in the first place.

So the final working command looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/awk '/<diskType typeName=".*\/>$/ && n == 0 { sub(/<diskType typeName=".*/, $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " <!--serial\=051161dc00000009 ""-->"""); ++n } { print }' Media1.cfgx > editedVol0.xml
```

the important part being the removal of the quotes that were around the serial number and the addition of a space and then 2 quote after the serial number. This is what tells awk that the item directly preceeding the "" is a string regardless of what awk may guess it to be.

```
 <!--serial\=051161dc00000009 ""-->""")
```

Thank you Lawson Hanson from 1997 for leading to this answer!
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/uS9LL99-agQ

Comment: There is zero difference between `" <!--serial\=051161dc00000009 ""-->"""` and `" <!--serial=051161dc00000009 -->"`. The stuff about adding `""` to tell awk you're using a string is about regexp comparisons, nothing to do with your question or your script. The thing that was causing your problem of leading zeros being stripped was writing the numeric part as a number instead of a string `"x"03"y"` vs `"x03y"`.

Comment: the difference between the two lines is the two " before the -->. While there are always multiple ways to accomplish the same thing, what I was trying to do was add the comment to the end of the line by using an awk command to replace the line with a new line that included the serial. The only thing that didn't work was the fact that the serial number was getting changed. I was trying to understand why. The answer I posted is the reason why this was happening. So the "" added after the number is a very important change that is the reason why the code I was attempting wasn't working.

Comment: No, it's not. Removing the `"` before and after the number is what fixed your problem, ie. the fix is changing `" <!--serial="051161dc00000009"-->"` to `" <!--serial=051161dc00000009-->"` so the number is inside the string (and so will be reproduced as-is like any string) rather than outside the string (and so will be treated like a number and have leading `0`s stripped). All the extra `"`s you added are doing nothing,they're just spurious null strings. You also don't need to escape `=` as it is not a metacharacter in any position.

Comment: btw - using `sub()` for this is fragile as it'll fail if/when your input contains `&` (and others?). Just do what I show in http://stackoverflow.com/a/43288729/1745001